# Improve the time efficiency of the anagram string function

Tags: python-3.x, performance, time, anagram

How can I improve the time efficiency of my algorithm to solve the following problem?

**Problem:**
Write a function that takes in a dictionary and query, two string arrays.
It should return an array of integers where each element i contains the number
of anagrams of the query[i] that exists in the dictionary. An anagram of a string is
another string with the same characters in the same frequency, in any order.

Example: "bca", "abc", "cba", "cab" are all anagram of "abc".

**Current Solution**

```
from collections import defaultdict


def IsAnagram(word):
    # a list of 26 elements, each represents the number of occurrence of every english letter in the word
    lst = [0] * 26
    for c in word:
        lst[ord(c) - 97] += 1
    return lst


def anagram_string(query, dictionary):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    res = []
    for w_1 in query:
        # if the anagram of w_1 was counted before
        if w_1 in d:
            res.append(d[w_1])
        else:
            # define num of anagram for the query in dictionary
            num_anagram = 0
            # loop through all words of the dictionary
            for w_2 in dictionary:
                if len(w_1) != len(w_2):
                    continue
                # add 1 to num of anagrams in case all letters of word_1 are the same as in word_2.
                num_anagram += IsAnagram(w_1) == IsAnagram(w_2)
            res.append(num_anagram)
            # record the word with its number of anagrams in the dictionary
            d[w_1] = num_anagram
    return res
```

The above code has a Time Complexity of O(n*m) where n is the number of words in the query array and m is the number of words in dictionary array. Although it works fine for a small length array, it takes forever to compute the out array for a list of length 5000+. So, how can I improve it or maybe if someone has a different idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in Javascript

```js
const dictionary = ['hack', 'rank', 'khac', 'ackh', 'kran', 'rankhacker', 'a', 'ab', 'ba', 'stairs', 'raits']

const query = ['a', 'nark', 'bs', 'hack', 'stairs']

function evaluate (dictionary, query) {
    const finalResult = query.reduce((map, obj) => {
      map[obj.split('').sort().join('')] = 0 
      return map
    }, {})
    dictionary.forEach(item => {
      const stringEvaluate = item.split('').sort().join('')   
        if (finalResult.hasOwnProperty(stringEvaluate)) {
          finalResult[stringEvaluate]++
        }
    })
    return Object.values(finalResult)
}

console.log(evaluate(dictionary, query))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in Python returning count of anagram in sequence which was found in dictionary list.

```
dictionary = ['hack', 'rank', 'khac', 'ackh', 'kran', 'rankhacker', 'a', 'ab', 'ba', 'stairs', 'raits']

query = ['a', 'nark', 'bs', 'hack', 'stairs']


myList=[sorted(element) for element in dictionary]

def anagram_string(query, dictionary):
    resList=[]
    for element in query:
        count = myList.count(sorted(element))
        resList.append(count)
    return resList

print(anagram_string(query,dictionary))
```